# Divs being messed up when using relatives and floats

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move two `divs` with the images next to the `left divs` but they are under them. What I missing here?

**[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3dLt3oss/)**

**CSS**

```
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;

}
#header {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;

}
.clear {
    clear: both;    
}

#header p, #header h1, #header h2 {
    padding:.4em 15px 0 15px;
    margin:0;
}
#header ul {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    margin:10px 0 2px 0;
    padding:0;
}
#header ul li {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header ul li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 1px;
    padding:3px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#eee;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
    background:#369;
    color:#fff;
}
#header ul li a.active, #header ul li a.active:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#header ul li a span {
    display:block;
}
#rand_v{
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 130px;
    padding:1em;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    border:1px solid #bcbcbc;
}
#rand_p{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    padding:1em;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    border:1px solid #bcbcbc
}
.box {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
    float:right;
    min-width:30%;
    height:242px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;

}
.littlebox {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    margin:10px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 5px;

}
table{
    width:555px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what is the expected output. Can you explain please?

Comment: Whats your problem will you able to elaborate them.

Comment: I need both divs with the images up next to the other 2 div that are on the left.

Comment: I really don't understand why is this downvote? What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this : **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3dLt3oss/2/)**

css:

```
.fl {
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="fl">
        <div id="rand_v">
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="rand_p">
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you .box got no positioning

try to give .box `position: absolute;` and a `top` value

http://jsfiddle.net/g0tfg5x7/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it would be useful for you.

1. add containers for #rand_v and #rand_p divs (.left_container) and .box div (.box_container)
2. add .box div top:0;
3. Create rules for divs

as the following:

```
.left_container {
        float:left;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .box_container {
        position:relative;
    }
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLt3oss/)

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I've made it already with @Kiran's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I make some changes on **html**

```
<div id="side">
    <div id="rand_v">
       <p>1</p>
       <p>2</p>
       <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rand_p">
       <p>1</p>
       <p>2</p>
       <p>3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and give **css** as

```
#side
{
  width: 175px;
    float:left;
}

.box {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
    float:left;             // changed
    min-width:30%;
    height:242px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3dLt3oss/3/)